# How to get a variable from another class in Java

Tags: java

Please anyone help me. i make two class in source package in java. ex one.java and two.java. in two.java, i make a global variable with data type int and value equal 10. so, can you tell me how to call a global variable from two.java in one.java.

Comment: If with global variable you mean static variable, you can access it using One.nameOfVariable

Comment: can you tell with more specific, i has been try but the result are still the same

Comment: Check Newaz Sharif’s answer

Comment: yeah exactly, thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets create a class like this

```
public class GlobalClass {
        public static int myGlobalValue = 10;
    }
```

then you can use this variable from any class like this

```
int globalValue = GlobalClass.myGlobalValue;
```

Comment: Hi @zendaris if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Create your own class**

```
public class YourClass {
    public static String YOUR_VALUE = 'Hello i am a value of this class';
}
```

**Declare and call that value :**

```
String value = YourClass.YOUR_VALUE;

TextView text = (TextView).findViewById('yourId');

text.setText(value);
```